# Mongoose query skipped over

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a function in NodeJS that makes a query into Mongo. The function is "checkForMatchingEmail".

```
var result = checkForMatchingEmail(req.body.email);

if ( result === 1) { // something something }
else if ( result === 0) { // something something }
```

I want to use the RESULT variable for deciding on what to do next. (sending a response to the front-end whether such an e-mail exists in DB).

The problem is that the query to Mongo seems to lag a bit, so the thread just skips over it and the if/else tree is useless, because the query results are not in yet.

What to do?

EDIT:

checkForMatchingEmail looks like this:

```
function checkForMatchingEmail(email) {
    var result = 0;

    User.findOne({email: email}, function(err,obj) {
        console.log("email is " + email);

        if (err) {
            return handleError(err);
        } else if (obj != null) {
            console.log("This email already exists." + obj);
            result = 1;
        } else if (obj === null) {
            result = 0;
            console.log("This email does not exist.");
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: you need to use callbacks, javascript is async language

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Answer (score 1):

First of all node.js is asynchronous and evented. There are no threads in this context that could skip over.

When querying mongodb via mongoose you're using a model let's assume `User` to execute a query. A typical mongoose query looks something like this

```
User.find({ email : 'someone@example.com'}, function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    // Do something with the err
  }

  // Here you have your query result
});
```

Taking your code example you should extend `checkForMatchingEmail` with a callback argument in which you process the result

```
checkForMatchingEmail(req.body.email, function(result) {
  if ( result === 1) { // something something }
  else if ( result === 0) { // something something }
});
```

You might read [What is Node.js](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch2.html) chapter in Mixu's Node book that explains asynchronous execution in node.js quite well.